# Finding Petrov type of a metric

Tags: tensors, xact

Is there a subpackage in xAct (or another Mathematica package for general relativity calculations) to determine the Petrov type of a metric?

I understand that xAct has a lot of subpackages for different types of calculations, but I could not find a functionality for determining the Petrov classification of a metric.

Comment: Is general relativity at the edge nowadays?

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with the Petrov classification but I suspect the most productive way to tackle this might be to use the spinor methods described in Section 13.2 of Wald.  In particular, one might be able to construct the polynomial $f(z)$ in Eq. (13.2.43) and then use standard Mathematica routines to find whether $f(z)$ has repeated roots.